# Integer range when using 64bit jdk

Tags: java, netbeans, 64-bit

As I understand the difference between two integer from 32bit & 64bit are the following:
32bit range  −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
64bit range: −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807

I am using a 64bit jdk, I validate it by printing the following:
System.out.println("JVM Bit size: " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));

> > > JVM Bit size: 64

when I try to init a new Integer variable with number bigger ther 10 letters I get a compilation error. why is that? it looks like the 64bit is larger

example (ran on netbeans):
int x = 12345678910; => Error: integer is too large

Comment: There's no such thing as an integer of 64 bits. Probably you're looking for `long`.

Comment: it means the JDK is 64 bit, it means its memory pointer is in 64bits in size. it doesn't mean you can assign a big number in int, even 32 bit application/cpu would have 128/256 bits numbers

Comment: Info about jvm 32bit and 64bit: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The size of an `int` in Java is completely independent of the 32-bitness or 64-bitness of a JDK.  It is always 4 bytes = 32 bits = −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

If you want a 64-bit integer, use a `long`, which is always 64 bits = 8 bytes.

Comment: int var=2147483647; - OK
long var64=9223372036854775806;=>Error msg: The literal 9223372036854775806 of type int is out of range 

do you know why I am getting this error?, if long represent the 64bit shouldn't it be valid to this range?

Thanks

Comment: You need to mark the literal as a `long` literal by adding an `L` at the end: `9223372036854775806L`.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike other languages, Java's numeric primitive types are always the same size, whatever the platform (32bit or 64bit, LE or BE); they are all big endian and are 1 byte long for `byte`, 2 bytes long for `short` and `char`, 4 bytes long for `int` and 8 bytes long for `long`.

If it were not the case, jars would not be portable across platforms...

Answer (score 3):

Your best resource is [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units
>
> 4.2.1. Integral Types and Values
>
> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> 1. For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> 2. For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> 3. **For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive**
> 4. **For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive**
> 5. For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535